# Android Studio - Writing text to a file using a Save button in the menu

Tags: android, text-editor

I am a beginner to Android apps and I am sorry for wasting your time. But I have struggled for a while on this topic. I am building a text editor, and I have a Save button in a menu. I am trying to figure out how to make the Save button save the contents of a text area to a file. I have only one issue in my code, which is at "public void saveText(View v){": It says cannot resolve symbol V...

```
package natanrosenfeld.texteditor;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.natanrosenfeld.texteditor.R;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You opened Settings.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_save: {
            public void saveText(View v){
                try {
                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("TextFile", MODE_APPEND));
                    EditText ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                   String text = ET.getText().toString();
                    out.write(text);
                    out.write('\n');
                    out.close();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Save not implemented yet.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have copy-pasted your code wrong. This shouldn't compile: `case R.id.action_save: {
            public void saveText(View v)`, since you can't define methods in other methods. Unless that { creates some kind of funky internal class that the compiler accepts... Either way, the formatting's a real mess.

Comment: Because of the error "Cannot resolve symbol V" that is why I cannot run my app...

Comment: you put method inside method. just remove your public void savetext

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira, now my brackets at the bottom say "Missing return statement..."

Comment: my eyes hurt trying to read your code. tidy it up first

Comment: I explained that I was a beginner. This is driving me crazy yet it is probably so simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -MainActivity.class;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You opened Settings.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_save:

            savetext();

            break;

    }
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void savetext () {
    try {

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("TextFile", MODE_APPEND));
        EditText ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String text = ET.getText().toString();
        out.write(text);
        out.write('\n');
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Save not implemented yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

R.layout.activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></RelativeLayout>
```

R.menu.menu_main

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_save" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" /></menu>
```

Comment: Now it says "Missing return statement" on the brackets at the bottom. Also says "Class or interface expected"

Comment: "}" expected... I thought it worked and when I tried to run it, it failed again.

Comment: Great news :) Keep on coding :)

Comment: what does logcat says this time.

Comment: Error. Reached end of file while parsing.

Comment: It is because there is a missing bracket } at the end.

Comment: Still says missing return statement after I add the brackets. If i add a suggested return statement, it underlines this line (return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);) in red.

Comment: can you please try moving the "return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);" to where it suggests you to put the return statement.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Give me a minute to run it

Comment: Doesn't work either. Now when I run my app, it crashes.

Comment: Do you have SettingsActivity.class in your project? By the way one of the brackets was out of the code window above, i have corrected it now. can you try again?

Comment: I have tried again. Same result. I do have SettingsActivity in my project.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in "savetext" it should be SaveText...im running again. Update: same result

Comment: I do. I just checked.

Comment: You should use the same values-they are case sensitive- for both savetext(); and public void savetext().

Comment: Thats strange because it works perfectly on my PC. Can you also add your activity_main.xml and menu_main.xml to your question above.

Comment: I tried that. Still crashes. I will add the other files.

Comment: Check my edit, replace them as i copied above. it should work, you have errors in your xml files.

Comment: Happy it worked at the end:) Please accept my answer.

Comment: How do I accept your answer, is there a button? Never mind, I got it